# Docker push failing to Dockerhub - tag does not exist

Tags: docker, bitbucket, cicd, docker-registry, bitbucket-pipelines

My bitbucket pipelines are failing with tag does not exist referring to  dockerhub image push

this is the bitbucket-pipelines.yaml config

```yaml
image: node:8

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        name: Build Docker Image
        caches:
          - docker
        script:
          - echo 'Building Docker image but skipping Deploy for feature branch'
          - sh ./build-docker.sh
  branches:
    development:
      - step:
          name: Deploy to Development
          caches:
            - docker
          deployment: test
          script:
            - export DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0
            - export LABEL=$(TZ=':America/Phoenix' date +%Y%m%d%H%M)
            - sh ./deploy.sh development ${LABEL}
```

and the build-docker.sh being

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
ENVIRONMENT=${1}
BITBUCKET_COMMIT=${BITBUCKET_COMMIT}
BITBUCKET_BRANCH="${BITBUCKET_BRANCH:-${ENVIRONMENT}}"
# Build Docker image
docker login -u ${DOCKER_USER} -p ${DOCKER_PASSWORD}
docker build -t intraedge/truyo-php:${ENVIRONMENT}-${BITBUCKET_COMMIT} -t intraedge/truyo-php:${ENVIRONMENT} --build-arg env=${ENVIRONMENT} .

if [[ $BITBUCKET_BRANCH == 'oci-poc' ]] || [[ $BITBUCKET_BRANCH == 'development' ]] || [[ $BITBUCKET_BRANCH == 'staging' ]] || [[ $BITBUCKET_BRANCH == 'qa' ]] || [[ $BITBUCKET_BRANCH == 'master' ]]; then
# and push to repository
docker push intraedge/truyo-php:${ENVIRONMENT}
docker push intraedge/truyo-php:${ENVIRONMENT}-${BITBUCKET_COMMIT}

fi;
```

Here is the deploy.sh

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

ENV=${1}
COMMIT=${BITBUCKET_COMMIT}-${2}

# Build Docker image and push to repository
docker login -u ${DOCKER_USER} -p ${DOCKER_PASSWORD}
docker build -t intraedge/truyo-php:${ENV}-${COMMIT} -t intraedge/truyo-php:${ENV} --build-arg env=${ENV} .
docker push intraedge/truyo-php:${ENV}
docker push intraedge/truyo-php:${ENV}-${COMMIT}
```

Comment: What **exactly** is the error you receive?

Comment: @Phil The push refers to repository [docker.io/******/****]
tag does not exist:

Comment: @Phil these indentations are working fine. May be I did not copy it and pasted correctly

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are not providing any value to the Environment Variable - `ENVIRONMENT`

```
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        name: Build Docker Image
        caches:
          - docker
        script:
          - echo 'Building Docker image but skipping Deploy for feature branch'
          - sh ./build-docker.sh <Provide_Some_Value>
```

You need to add some value over here as per your .sh file - `sh ./build-docker.sh <Provide_Some_Value>`.

As per your bash script, it is expecting some value at the first flag

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
ENVIRONMENT=${1}
```

For Example :- `sh ./build-docker.sh Prod`

After this, you won't receive the error.

Comment: branches:
    development:
      - step:
          name: Deploy to Development
          caches:
            - docker
          deployment: test
          script:
            - export DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0
            - export LABEL=$(TZ=':America/Phoenix' date +%Y%m%d%H%M)
            - sh ./deploy.sh development ${LABEL}

Comment: You have provided flag to `./deploy.sh ` i.e. - development. However error seems to be coming from sh ./build-docker.sh since that part is adding tag to the docker image.

Can you share the deploy.sh part as well? to understand what script is doing

Comment: #!/usr/bin/env bash

ENV=${1}
COMMIT=${BITBUCKET_COMMIT}-${2}

# Build Docker image and push to repository
docker login -u ${DOCKER_USER} -p ${DOCKER_PASSWORD}
docker build -t ******/*****:${ENV}-${COMMIT} -t *****/******:${ENV} --build-arg env=${ENV} .
docker push intraedge/truyo-php:${ENV}
docker push intraedge/truyo-php:${ENV}-${COMMIT}

Comment: Can you do an echo in this script to check if you are getting the value over here :-

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
ENVIRONMENT=${1}
echo $ENVIRONMENT
```